# get X-CSRF-Token value from txt batch windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I have to get the value of X-CSRF-Token from a txt file that contains the response of my Curl. How do i get this value in a batch in windows?

my txt is like this:

---

```
some html

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: X-SMP-SESSIDSSO=6B62CDA6DB4326BBE8A8E257E0A53B03; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-SMP-SESSID=7B454C62CAED6F6BE349BD48AF7554AB8820EB5AAE2B2221CEED96AAB9CEB2B0; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-CSRF-Token: 51F4E34B4967FFB235C370C92E566AC9
Allow: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1013
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 16:45:58 GMT
```

---

I need to put `51F4E34B4967FFB235C370C92E566AC9` into a variable.
Thanks

Comment: should be quite easy - if only we knew, what a X-CSRF-Token is and how your file looks like.

Answer (score 0):

find the line ( with `findstr`) and take the second token (space is a Default delimiter):

```
for /f  "Tokens=2" %%i in ('findstr /b "X-CSRF-Token:" curl.txt') do set token=%%i
echo %token%
```